# better way than set .git on root directory for Laravel

Tags: git, laravel

So I'm setting up my Lavarel website on a shared webhost, as recommended by Laravel, every file but the "public" dir should be above hosts public_html for security reasons, what's the best way to track it with .git ?

My local file structure

```
repo
  .git
  laravel_files
    **dirs and files **
  public
    assets
    upload
    vendor
    index.php
```

My webhost file structure

```
root
  .git
  .gitignore
  **a bunch of hidden files that cannot be tracked**
  laravel_files
    **dirs and files that need to be tracked **
  public_html
    assets
    upload
    vendor
    index.php
    other folder (subdomain for testing to be ignored)
    other folder (subdomain for testing to be ignored)
    ...
```

As seen above, the git works fine locally with 2 dirs only but on the host the .git would need to be located on the root dir?

I did that by .gitignore'ing all but those 2 Laravel's dirs, the problem is that I have some dirs inside public_html that are their own repos and git doesn't work correctly

My other option would be having 2 repos, 1 for laravel dir and another for public dir (so I can still have my sub domains as it's own repos, but it's not convenient to have 1 project on 2 repos)

Or a 3rd option is to have public dir back inside laravel dir and have apaches 
.htaccess pointing to laravel_dir/public/index.php but I suspect that I wouldn't be able to use my sub domains anymore? And is prone to security issues

Any other ideas? What's the best way to accomplish this? 
With my file structure but still able to use dirs below repo's location as their own repos?

Answer (score 0):

Depending you your hoster, I can tell what I do on mine:

```
public_html
   example.com  // This contains the complete Laravel installation
      .git
      app
      bootstrap
      config
      public
      ...
```

Then I let point the document root of the server to `public_html/example.com/public`. None of the other document roots point to just `public_html`.

Another approach might be the following:

```
example.com  // This contains the complete Laravel installation
    .git
    app
    bootstrap
    config
    public // symlinked to public_html/example.com
    ...
public_html
    example.com
```

Then your document root should point to `public_html/example.com`